# expo-location (react native) app crashing on android after getting current location using the static method Location.getCurrentPositionAsync()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-maps

My expo managed (react native) app crushes on android  after getting the current location.

[image]

when i comment out the line  `const locate = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync()` and other lines that depend on it ,the app does not crush..so am thinking its crushing on android because of the static method from expo-location

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import * as Location from "expo-location"
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons"
import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps"

export const LocationScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null)

 useEffect(() => {
    ;(async () => {
      const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync()
      if (status !== "granted") {
        setError("Permission to access location was denied")
        return
      }
      if (status === "granted") {
        const locate = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync()
        setLocation(locate.coords)
      }
    })()
  }, [])
 
return (
 <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
          <MapView style={styles.map}>
            {location ? (
              <Marker coordinate={location} title="My location">
                <FontAwesome name="map-marker" size={40} color={colors.palette.map} />
              </Marker>
            ) : (
              <Text>{error}</Text>
            )}
          </MapView>
        </View>
)

}
```

Am using

"expo": "^46.0.0",

"expo-location": "~14.3.0",

"react-native": "0.69.7",

"react": "18.0.0",

Comment: looks like the crash is related to use of maps and possibly the marker you have on the map rather than the location itself - AirMapManager is the code that manages the map

Comment: Thanks  @BenClayton I have updated the question to include the map code from react-native-maps ,what could be causing it?

Comment: are you sure the type of locate.coords and <Marker coordinate={location}/> are compatible?